# How to properly check for messages from the telnet server?

Tags: go, telnet

I am trying to make a telnet client using the [go-telnet](https://github.com/reiver/go-telnet) library. I am able to connect to the server, but I was expecting to receive some data to login in with user and password.

But I don't get any message. What I could do until now is just send a message to the server and the server prints it.

If I connect using a regular telnet client first thing I have to do is to log in with user and password. I want to replicate this using my own client.

I don't see any examples on GitHub on how to send or receive messages so I am a little confused.

Here is my current code:

```
func main() {

    err = telnet.DialToAndCall("192.168.206.226:23", caller{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

type caller struct {}

func (c caller) CallTELNET(ctx telnet.Context, w telnet.Writer, r telnet.Reader) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
}
```

Are there any other steps I need to do when connecting? Or am I doing something wrong?

edit (reading part):

```
//var data []byte
for {
    //numBytes, err := conn.Read(data)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println(reader.ReadString('\n'))
}
```

Comment: If you want a login prompt, you need to connect the telnet service to a login service of some sort. There's nothing about the telnet protocol itself that does this.

Comment: @Flimzy: not really sure I understand. From everywhere I connect to that IP and port 23 I get a login prompt back. Shouldn't I ge that back too ?

Comment: Only if you've written your telnet server that way.

Comment: Your code here doesn't show you reading or writing anything to the telnet connection. Can you share the actual code you're using?

Comment: @JimB: I add the reading part that I have. I also tried to check the bytes received in the past, and it was always 0. With this code, I don't get anything.

Comment: @Kobe: I'm still confused, this only reads `os.Stdin`. You're first example just echoes whatever you send to stdin, it's not doing anything with the telnet connection at all. Have you tried reading and writing to the telnet connection?

Comment: @JimB: that's the thing. I don't really know how, there are basically 0 examples on the internet on how to do this in Go. That is what's stopping me. I was hopping someone did this in Go until now.

Comment: @Kobe: There's probably no examples, because no one really uses telnet anymore. This library is a bit odd, but the method signature shows it providing you with a Reader and Writer for the telnet connection -- try using them.

Comment: ok, I will try that. I am not that familiar yet on how to use readers and writers in Go, but I'll read some tutorials. Thanks.